# How to use transaction through multiple layer code in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, transactions

Suppose my project is like [.net petshop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479070.aspx).
It has a BLL, DAL and SQLHelper.

Normally, I call a BLL function in my web layer, and the BLL function calls the DAL function and finally, the DAL call the sqlhelper.

But in some situations, I nedd a transaction.

For example:

Web layer:

I need Call some BLL functions.
Code as below:

```
var m = BLLFunction_1();

var n=  BLLFunction_2();

if (m+n<100)
{
// need rollback here
}
else
{
BLLFunction_3();
// commit here 
}
```

So it makes me have to use a transaction object in the web layer, to pass it into the BLL function, and BLL layer pass it into DAL layer, and finally pass it into SQLHelper.

That's a little ugly.

I wonder what is a elegant methed to this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are looking for Transaction in ADO.NET.

Basically you need to wrap your "actions" into a TransactionScope.

```
    try
    {
        using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //perform SQL
            using(SqlHelper sh = new SqlHelper())
            {
                //do stuff
            }

            //call new DAL function

            //call other DAL function

            ts.Complete();            
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi create Transaction in your BLL functions with TransactionScopeOption Required

```
public void BLLFunction_1()
   {     
       using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
       {
           //do ur stuff here

           ts.Complete();
       }
   }

    public void BLLFunction_2()
   {     
       using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
       {
           //do ur stuff here

           ts.Complete();
       }
   }
```

With TransactionScopeOption Required : A transaction is required by the scope. It uses an ambient transaction if one already exists. Otherwise, it creates a new transaction before entering the scope. This is the default value. So here your BLLFunction_2 will use the Transaction of BLLFunction_1 instead of creating new.

Comment: In your example there is no nested execution, and appears to be no overarching transaction scope; why wouldn't this just result in two separate transactions being completed independently?

Comment: That is because of TransactionScopeOption Required . If you want to execute say BLLFunction_2 transaction independently then TransactionScopeOption should be RequiresNew for second transaction

Comment: Interesting, without some form of external scoping call to establish a new transaction scope I never would have expected this to work as intended.  The OP shows two sequential function calls BLL_1 followed by BLL_2, each appearing to establish an entirely new transaction scope and complete it.  I need to read up on this, it seems counter-intuitive.